# My java script array doesn't have a length

Tags: javascript, razor, model-view-controller

I have the following code:

```
//Populate inputData with the values of the input text boxes, in order
var inputData = {};
var x = document.getElementById("newInventoryForm");

//Added this following line in the edit
$('#additionalContent').append("My x.length property " + x.length + "<br/>");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {// -1 so we don't get the submit button
    var addData = {
        id : x[i].id,
        value : x[i].value
    };
    inputData[i] = addData;
    $('#additionalContent').append(inputData[i].id + " : " + inputData[i].value + "<br/>");
}
```

I'm attempting to pass the form data from a previously made form to another javascript function. Before I do that I have tried to make it all work in the same .js page, however when I try to output my `inputData` through a for loop, it shows up blank. I determined this is because `inputData.length` is `undefined`. I was under the impression that declaring it as `inputData = {};` made it an array and thus had a default length value. How can I change this to have the correct length?

#### Edit

Several commenters have said that `var x = document.getElementById("newInventoryForm");` should return null or a node, neither of which has a length property. Adding the line in the code above, has produced this output.

My x.length property 18
serialNumber : 456
someDatafield : someInput

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared it as an object.

Perhaps `var inputData = [];` will give you better results.

Comment: SLaks (below) makes a good point. Perhaps you want var x = $('#newInventoryForm');

also [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) may be something to look into.

Comment: @JordanDavidson It's odd that he says it doesn't return an array because the code as I had it works. Just the inputData.length didn't work (for obvious reasons now, thank you). It produces the form data like "id, value", is this something that shouldn't work and for some reason does? Should I change it to var x= $('#newInventoryForm'); to ensure it works all the time?

Comment: Using the jQuery notation will give you something to iterate through for sure, but it may not be what you are looking for. Take a look at the array you get with `var x = $('#newInventoryForm').serializeArray();`

Answer (score 0):

`{}` is an object, not an array.
You want `[]`.

Also, `getElementById()` does not return an array; your entire code makes no sense.